# Save a list of data into core data iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm doing save a list of data into core data by using the for each loop here. However, it only helping me to save the last data in the for loop into core data, what problem is it? I couldn't manage to save all the data into core data. Below is my code that I'm working on it...

```
let appDelegate : AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context : NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let category = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Category", inManagedObjectContext:context)


RestApiManager.sharedInstance.makeGetRequest("testingserver", onCompletion: {json in
    for result in json["record"].arrayValue
    {
        print(result)
        let id = result["mc_termid"].stringValue
        let name = result["mc_name"].stringValue
        let parent = result["mc_parent"].stringValue
        let color = result["mc_color"].stringValue
        let update = result["mc_updated"].stringValue
        let termName = result["mc_termname"].stringValue
        let status = result["mc_status"].stringValue

        category.setValue(id, forKey: "mc_termid")
        category.setValue(name, forKey: "mc_name")
        category.setValue(parent, forKey: "mc_parent")
        category.setValue(color, forKey: "mc_color")
        category.setValue(update, forKey: "mc_updated")
        category.setValue(termName, forKey: "mc_termname")
        category.setValue(status, forKey: "mc_status")
    }
    do
    {
        try context.save()
        print("Category save to local database successfully.")
    }
    catch
    {

    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert an managedobject every time you iterate one element in the array.
So put the category declaration into the iterating block.

```
let appDelegate : AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let context : NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext


RestApiManager.sharedInstance.makeGetRequest("testingserver", onCompletion: {json in
    for result in json["record"].arrayValue
    {
        let category = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Category", inManagedObjectContext:context)

        print(result)
        let id = result["mc_termid"].stringValue
        let name = result["mc_name"].stringValue
        let parent = result["mc_parent"].stringValue
        let color = result["mc_color"].stringValue
        let update = result["mc_updated"].stringValue
        let termName = result["mc_termname"].stringValue
        let status = result["mc_status"].stringValue

        category.setValue(id, forKey: "mc_termid")
        category.setValue(name, forKey: "mc_name")
        category.setValue(parent, forKey: "mc_parent")
        category.setValue(color, forKey: "mc_color")
        category.setValue(update, forKey: "mc_updated")
        category.setValue(termName, forKey: "mc_termname")
        category.setValue(status, forKey: "mc_status")
    }
    do
    {
        try context.save()
        print("Category save to local database successfully.")
    }
    catch
    {

    }
})
```

Comment: seriously? I'm doing a careless mistake?haha

Comment: You help me on this dude, I did it now...I've careless mistake omg

Comment: Happy coding! :) Most of the time it is just a silly mistakes making the whole project stopped!